# Mui Datepicker show red text before validation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Mui Date picker and date time picker and when I just open the modal I see this:

[image]

I don't want the red text at least I enter a wrong date, but I can't find an attribute to change this.

One of those components is the following:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={DateAdapter}>
              <DesktopDatePicker
                label={translation.word.startDate}
                inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                value={startDate}
                onChange={handleStartDateChange}
                shouldDisableDate={disablePastDays}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    {...validator.getFieldProps("start_date")}
                    variant="standard"
                    fullWidth
                  />
                )}
              />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `value` is `null` before error in `TextField` :

```
<TextField
   {...params}
   {...validator.getFieldProps("start_date")}
   error={startDate !== null && validator.getFieldProps("start_date").error}      // Add this
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

have your useState value for the startDate const as null. That will do the trick.

```
const [startDate , setStartDate ] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(
        null,
    );
```